# Global variable doesn't update prior to next loop

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm trying to build a tachometer in C++ for my ESP32.  When I uncomment `Serial.printf("outside rev: %d \n", rev);` outside of the conditional it works, but when I comment it I get values that are orders of magnitude greater than they should be (700 revolutions without, vs 7 revolutions with).  My best guess is that the print statement is slowing the `loop()` down just enough for `incrementRevolutions()` to toggle the global variable `passedMagnet` from true to false before the next loop. That would make sense, since a delay in updating passedMagnet would allow `newRevCount++;` to be triggered multiple times.  But this is obviously something I can't debug with either print statements or step-through debugging given the time-sensitive nature of the race condition.

```
bool passedMagnet = true;
int incrementRevolutions(int runningRevCount, bool passingMagnet)
{
//    Serial.printf("passedMagnet: %d ,  passingMagnet %d , runningRevCount: %d \n", passedMagnet, passingMagnet, runningRevCount);
    int newRevCount = runningRevCount;
    if (passedMagnet && passingMagnet)
    { //Started a new pass of the magnet
        passedMagnet = false;
        newRevCount++;
    }
    else if (!passedMagnet && !passingMagnet)
    { //The new pass of the magnet is complete
        passedMagnet = true;
    }
    return newRevCount;
}

unsigned long elapsedTime = 0;
unsigned long intervalTime = 0;
int rev = 0;
void loop()
{
    intervalTime = millis() - elapsedTime;
    rev = incrementRevolutions(rev, digitalRead(digitalPin));

//    Serial.printf("outside rev: %d \n", rev);
    if (intervalTime > 1000)
    {
        Serial.printf("rev: %d \n", rev);
        rev = 0;
        elapsedTime = millis();
    }
}
```

Is this a known gotcha with Arduino or C++ programming?  What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is a known "gotcha" with "C programming", specifically: undefined behavior. There's a bug somewhere in the code that you didn't show that ends up corrupting memory, which manifests itself with random behavior that changes when something as innocent as a print statement gets added. You will need to find the bug, somewhere in the code that's not shown, and fix it.

Comment: There isn't much more to the full codebase.  It's available here: https://github.com/jamesjmtaylor/esp32-ftms-server
Do you have any suggestions on how I can find the bug?  Are there profiler or other debugging tools that you would recommend?

Comment: Why don't you profile it with micros()? See how long it takes with and without `Serial.printf()` and you should know if that's the bottleneck

Comment: Using micros() I found that the loop took 33334
microseconds with `Serial.printf()` and 17708 without, so almost twice as long.

Comment: the language you're using is not C. It is a C++ compiler used in conjunction with a custom standard library

Comment: Updated question to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the test is to blame.  I had to rename and move things a bit to visualize the logic, sorry about that.

```
bool magStateOld = false;  // initialize to digitalRead(digitalPin) in setup()

int incrementRevolutions(int runningRevCount, bool magState)
{
    int newRevCount = runningRevCount;

    // detect positive edge.
    if (magState && !magStateOld)      // <- was eq. to if (magState && magStateOld)
                                       // the large counts came from here.  
    { 
        newRevCount++;
    }
    magStateOld = magState; // record last state unconditionally

    return newRevCount;
}
```

You could also write it as...

```
int incrementRevolutions(int n, bool magState)
{
    n += (magState && !magStateOld);
    magStateOld = magState;
    return n;
}
```

But the most economical (and fastest) way of doing what you want would be:

```
bool magStateOld;

inline bool positiveEdge(bool state, bool& oldState)
{
    bool result = (state && !oldState);
    oldState = state;
    return result;
}  

void setup()
{
  // ...

  magStateOld = digitalRead(digitalPin);
}

void loop()
{
    // ...

    rev += (int)positiveEdge(digitalRead(digitalPin), magStateOld);

    // ...
}
```

It's reusable, and saves both stack space and unnecessary assignments.

If you cannot get clean transitions from your sensor (noise on positive and negative edges, you'll need to debounce the signal a bit, using a timer.

Example:

```
constexpr byte debounce_delay = 50; // ms, you may want to play with
                                    // this value, smaller is better.
                                    // but must be high enough to 
                                    // avoid issues on expected
                                    // RPM range. 
                                    // 50 ms is on the high side.
    
byte debounce_timestamp;            // byte is large enough for delays 
                                    // up to 255ms. 

// ...

void loop()
{
    // ...

    byte now = (byte)millis();

    if (now - debounce_timestamp >= debounce_delay)
    {
        debounce_timestamp = now;
        rev += (int)positiveEdge(digitalRead(digitalPin), magStateOld);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I implemented your first suggestion and got a similar logging statement to what I had before: ```rev: 796 , instantaneousRpm: 7016.470588235 ```.  This occurred once per second.

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor  What are you measuring?  A hand crack, or a motor?  And don't forget the ! in the test

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor  I suggest you try turning the motor by hand, or used a magnet to trigger the sensor, to check the reading.   If you have a scope, check the signal for noise, and signal level.  It should be clean with a very quick rise to 2 volts or more.  If not, you will have to either use a delay to debounce it, or amplify the signal to a proper 5V digital level.

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor  There is something wrong about your RPM calculation as well.  796 ticks per second is 796 * 60 = 47760 RPM, not 7016 RPM..

Comment: At this point it's just a magnet that I move by hand back and forth in front of a hall sensor.  I copy & pasted the top code block exactly as you had it, then added `magStateOld = digitalRead(digitalPin)` to `setup()`  and got the same result.  I'm less concerned about RPM being wrong as I am about revolutions being wrong at this point.  One step at a time :)

Comment: That test is a latch, I've been using it as is for 30 years, so I know it works.  That's why I ask.  The initializaion in setup is to avoid reading a spurious turn on boot.  Just to be sure, the test is state and not oldstate.  and then store state to oldstate no matter what happens. This is to prevent the count from increasing while the magnet is close and/or in the right orientation.  There is a differentce between a turning magnet and a magnet appproaching, in that the field of the turning magnet is turning with the axis, that's important,  and it gets very close to  the sensor very fast.

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor Maybe your sensor is too sensitive.  By waving the magnet slowly in front of the sensor by hand, your expected reading should be close to 1, at the very least.  That's why I suspect it could be an electrical issue.  What's the part # of  the sensor you are using?  I'll look into it.

Comment: I'm currently using the Linear Magnetic Hall Sensor (part number SE014) https://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/media/allelectronics2018/spec/SE-14.pdf

Comment: Ok.  It should work.  Do you have a scope, or a voltmeter?  Best would be a scope, But first things first: I suppose your input is connected to D0, and not A0.  You can tune the sensitivity of the sensor.  It would be best for that if you could rig some kind of rig that woud keep the magent at a repeatable distance to the sensor.  You can glue it to a stick and find someting that would keep that in place while you turn it , best would be , some Meccano or lego pafts, a turn table, anything that tuurns or sllides and that would keep the magnett at a repeatable distance form the sensor.

Comment: Don't use too large of a magnet, the smaller the better.  Then you can tune the module by placing the magnet right below (or above) tthe sensor, about 3 to 5mm  awaiy from it. You  tune the sensor by truning VR1.  Ideally, you want a +5V signal when the magnet is closest to the sensor, and no signal as soon as possible when it moves away from that position.  You'll have to tune again for your final assembly.  Make a somewhat solid rig, since you'll use it for the duration of the project. If you have a scope, the signal from D0 should show clean, fast transitions. when the magnet passes under

Comment: I have a multimeter here at home.  I've turned the sensitivity down to as far as it will go.  I've confirmed input is connected to D0 and not A0.  That's good to know about the magnet size.  I'll pick the smallest one that I can find.

Comment: the sensor.  If you cannot get clean transitions, you will have to add some delay while reading.  I'll post the code to do that in the answer.  Adding delay is a bit trickey, since it will limit the max RPMs your app can read.  Good luck! @JamesJordanTaylor

Comment: Yep, I've already started playing with a `sampleTime`.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: you're welcome.  I really enjoy doing all things electronic. :)